# Como adicionar um elemento HTML no PDF através do iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, pdf, itextsharp

O itextsharp me permite adicionar os seus elementos de PDF, exemplo:

```
_documento.Add(new Paragraph("Olá"));
```

Mas eu gostaria de adicionar alguns elementos do HTML, como um `<h1>`, ou um `<p>`, como posso fazer?

```
_documento.Add(????);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você precisará usar um `HtmlWorker`:

```
    TextReader reader = new StringReader(html);
    HTMLWorker worker = new HTMLWorker(_documento);

    _documento.Open();
    worker.StartDocument();
    worker.Parse(reader);

    worker.EndDocument();
    worker.Close();
    _documento.Close();
```

Comment: Eu estava fazendo certo então. Só agora que percebi que o erro era porque meu html tinha uma imagem na qual o src era preenchido com uma imagem em base64 e não linkando num arquivo. Esse é o real problema, vou buscar uma solução e se não encontrar crio outra questão.